# Some trouble in javascript While using If/else

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript through Codecademy. There I was asked to make a rock paper and scissor game. I did it by coding the following:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!"
    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins"
        } else {
            return "paper wins"
        }
    } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins"
        } else {
            return "scissors wins"
        }
    } else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "rock wins"
        } else {
            return "scissors wins"
        }
    };
};
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

but later I myself added a code to stop unavailable choices like if any one choosed "egg"

```
var a = function() {
    if (userchoice !== "scissors") {
        if (userChoice !== "rock") {
            if (userChoice !== "paper") {
                console.log "unavilable"
            };
        };
    };
};
```

to check I typed "dog" but it didn't display"unavailable"

Comment: What is the problem, then?

Comment: You should not use `;` for `if` block

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: to check I typed "dog" but it didn't display"unavailable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 console.log "unavilable"
```

should be

```
 console.log("unavilable")
```

Also you need to call the function `a`:

```
compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
a();
```

**Update:**

```
if (userchoice !== "scissors") {  //Problem is here "userChoice" and not "userchoice"
```

See the *[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmspohkL/)*.

Comment: @srijanpoudel. How are you calling the function `a()` ?

Comment: function a don't have any parameters and the variable "userChoice" used is defined on very top.      var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

Comment: @srijanpoudel. You don't have to pass any parameter, just call it like I did. Also, I was talking abt spelling mistake. _C_ is caps in user**C**hoice. I added a fiddle for you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to concat the conditions

```
if(userchoice!="..." && userchoice!="...") 
console.log(...)
```

or even use

```
switch(userchoice) 
     case: "rock": 
     case: "paper": 
          console.log(...);
          break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mistyped `userChoice` with `userchoice`.

I would recommend you to implement a method inArray. The code will be more readable this way. Here is the code for it:

```
function inArray(needle, haystack){
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you are just calling it in your code. Here is a jsFiddle with the complete code: [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/9uh3gkpa/)